# Convert standard date format to string splitting by point in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One `df` have one column `date` which has the following format:

```
0         2019/5/20 22:49:29
1         2019/5/20 23:18:23
2           2019/3/8 9:11:35
3           2019/3/8 9:19:58
4         2019/5/20 22:57:12
5           2019/3/8 9:06:41
```

How can I convert it to format six digits `year.month.day` format? I have tried with the following code to but only get `year-month-day`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

But my desired output:

```
0         19.05.20
1         19.05.20
2         19.03.08
3         19.03.08
4         19.05.20
5         19.03.08
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want strings:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%y.%m.%d')

# if your date is not datetime type:
# df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%y.%m.%d')
```